# How to use specific private agent under agent pool without YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have setup 2 private agents under agent pool but when I run the pipeline I want a specific agent to run the pipeline but its not happening.

How to select or where to select specific agent to run the pipeline with YAML configuration.

Comment: Hi, just want to check whether Shayki's answer and update could help you? If yes, Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a demand with your agent name you want. you enter the demand in the yaml after the pool name:

```
pool:
   name: Private
   demands: Agent.Name -equals Test
```

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands).

Without YAML the demands exist under the Options tab:

[image]

Or per job:

[image]